# Capistrano deploys code to the server 15+ minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, deployment, capistrano

I am facing a problem with Capistrano while deploying code to the productions server. When I run

```
cap production deploy
```

the command takes up to 20 minutes.

What can be the problem of that? I have also a staging server where the process of deployment takes about 90-120 seconds. The staging server is created from the snapshot of the production server.

Why the deployment takes so much time? Where should I start with looking for the problem?

**EDIT:** Before I went to sleep, I ran the `cap production deploy` command and 7 hours later, there was just following:

```
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2014-12-18 01:04:22 executing `production'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * 2014-12-18 01:04:22 executing `multistage:ensure'
  * 2014-12-18 01:04:22 executing `deploy'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy'
  * 2014-12-18 01:04:22 executing `deploy:check_revision'
  * 2014-12-18 01:04:23 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2014-12-18 01:04:23 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:name/project.git master"
    command finished in 2906ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/deployer/apps/project-production/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/deployer/apps/project-production/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 18138753b77ec5b2a25c292536a512c1d7851448 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@bitbucket.org:name/project.git /home/deployer/apps/project-production/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/deployer/apps/project-production/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 18138753b77ec5b2a25c292536a512c1d7851448; fi"
    servers: ["IP"]
Password:
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 32534ms
    copying the cached version to /home/deployer/apps/project-production/releases/20141218000536
  * executing "cp -RPp /home/deployer/apps/project-production/shared/cached-copy /home/deployer/apps/project-production/releases/20141218000536 && (echo 18138753b77ec5b2a25c292536a512c1d7851448 > /home/deployer/apps/project-production/releases/20141218000536/REVISION)"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
    command finished in 1254ms
  * 2014-12-18 01:05:37 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2014-12-18 01:05:37 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/project-production/releases/20141218000536 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/project-production/releases/20141218000536/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/project-production/shared/bundle --quiet --no-cache --without development test"
    servers: ["IP"]
    [IP] executing command
^C*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/project-production/releases/20141218000536; true"
    servers: ["IP"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Errno::ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer - recvfrom(2)
```

After 7 hours, I cancelled it. Trying to run it again.

**EDIT2:** I just re-run the `cap production deploy` and it's successfully deployed now, but the process of deployment took 10 minutes.

I am not sure how to proceed this issue - where should I start with looking for the problem of slow deployment?

Comment: capistrano should be outputting status information.  Where is it hanging up?

Comment: hi, we need more information to go on here... do you have logs? can you tell us about your deployment environment? anything? otherwise it's a bit like Q: "something went wrong" A: "do something to fix it!" ;)

Comment: I added some additional info, guys.

Comment: Out of experience, we've had long deploys as well, really depends what's happening in the deploy like updating files, migrations and what not.